# JavaScript Onload property

Tags: javascript, onload

I have read some posts regarding the onload property. My understanding is that it is not a method, not an event, event listener, or trigger. It is merely a empty pointer to a function waiting to be assigned. Here is a shortened script. It assigns a image manipulation function upon event then renders the image to the web page. Instead of assign the function to onload which is the pointer to the function. Why can't I just execute the function directly? Am I making any sense here? Thanks

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = e.target.result;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    ......

    dataurl = canvas.toDataURL(file.type);
    document.getElementById('output').src = dataurl;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload):

> The **FileReader.onload** property contains an event handler executed when
>   the load event is fired, when content read with readAsArrayBuffer,
>   readAsBinaryString, **readAsDataURL** or readAsText is available.

So it's executed **after** reading content is done, that you're performing by calling `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`.

Answer (score 0):

`onload` is a field of the object [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) which handles a reference to the function that you wanna execute when the desired file gets loaded. Essentially, it's the callback that gets called when the event `load` is triggered. Why using this pattern and not executing the function directly? Because loading files is an asynchronous task (which is initialized with `readAsDataURL`, `readAsBinaryString`, `readAsArrayBuffer` or `readAsText`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the function directly because files load asynchronously.  You can convert the FileReader code to return a promise though and then you can use async/await to make the code look like you're directly calling it

```
funciton readFileAsDataURL(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(e.target.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
}

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image():
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = url;
  };
}

async function foo() {
  const result = await readFileAsDataURL(file);
  const img = await loadImage(result);
  // you can now use img
  ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in essence, OnLoad is an event handler (or reference to the event handler) for FileReader when it is called to further processes data when FileReader is done loading? Is my interpretation correct?